# Remove  emoji from string in php

Tags: php

I use telegram webhook, here is a sample of the data i receive:

> "⁣ #Amazon blabla"

It is stored in a variable string, and i want to remove

> "⁣ #Amazon"

But i have a problem with this emoji, i tried the following code:

```
$flag=preg_replace(" #Amazon","", $string)
```

but it does not work.

I also tried to find it by searching the characters that compose this emoji, but it has not printable character, so i don't know how to resolve it. Can you help me^?

Comment: you should use this https://github.com/BriquzStudio/php-emoji

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: As i said i want to remove " #Amazon" from the string, but the problem is how can i find the emoij .
I see github solution, it's ok but is there a most specific way? Because i need to eliminate this emoji, not the others